# Proving Invertibility and Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If matrix $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $A^2 -A -2I=0$. 
How can I show that $A$ is invertible and that $A^{-1} = \frac12(A-I)$?
Also, how do I show that one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is $2$ or $ -1$?
I appreciate any help on this question.

Answer (score 2):

Write $A^{2}-A=2I$. Factor out $A$ to get $A(A-I)=2I$.

For the eigenvalues, factor the original polynomial $A^{2}-A-2I$. What do the factors tell you?

Edit: Some details.

Divide both sides of $A(A-I)=2I$ by $2$. We have
$$A\cdot \frac{1}{2}(A-I)=I$$
Hence $A$ is invertible with inverse $\frac{1}{2}(A-I)$

For the eigenvalues

$$0=A-A-2I=(A+I)(A-2I)$$

Since the matrix $0$ is singular, either $A+I$ or $A-2I$ must be singular. This means one of them has a vector in the nullspace. Hence,

$$(A+I)v=0$$
or
$$(A-2I)v=0$$
for some $v\neq 0$.

Therefore either $1$ or $2$ is, by definition, an eigenvalue

Comment: I am omitting some details, hoping you can fill them in

Comment: We do not know that this is the characteristic polynomial of A.  I'd appreciate seeing that detail filled in.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot!